# object instance not set on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to load my website and it says object instance not found. What do i do??

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace? The error usually means you're trying to access a property on a null object. Debug it, and look at the objects being used in the page load method.

Comment: Please post the exception, the stacktrace, and the portion of code that is failing.  That will help people find what the problem is.  In general, you should try running your website in debug mode so you can walk through the page load yourself and more concretely determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the object that it is complaining about is instantiated before it is used...or check it for null before using it.  Can you post the actual error and code here so we can see more detail?

Answer (score 0):

More info please.

You flagged C# so can I assume ASP.NET? What version?
What version of IIS?
Did it ever work? Have you changed anything?
Can you strip stuff out to get soemthing working? Then add back a step at a time?